# JavaFX: Trigger on Pane not visible / destroyed

Tags: javafx, eventtrigger, pane

I want to fill a `Pane varPane` with variable content. The implementation looks similar to this

```
Pane varPane = new Pane();
// ..

someProperty.addListener(( obsv, oldV, newV) -> {
    varPane.getChildren().clear();    // Remove old Property Pane Content
    Pane propPane = getNewPane(newV);     // Get new content
    varPane.getChildren().add(propPane);  // add Content
});
```

The Pane is generated like:

```
public Pane getNewPane(Object newV){
       Pane myPane = new Pane();

       // Add dummy Content
        myPane.getChildren().add(new Label(newV.toString()))

        // Here I need some listener
        // somthing like [not working]:
        myPane.setOnClosed( System.out.println("Pane closed: " + newV.toString() );

        return myPane;
}
```

As indicated above, I need to perform some cleanup after the pane is not used anymore. However I couldn't find to correct way to implement such a listener.

The listener shall be triggered if:

- the content of  `varPane` is changed and the old Pane is not visible anymore, OR
- if `varPane` is destroyed (e.g. on `Platform.exit()`)

I could require that on these events an function is called for the cleanup. However I think it would be safer, if the pane detects such events on its own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First note that [`varPane.getChildren().removeAll()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/collections/ObservableList.html#removeAll-E...-) doesn't do what you think. You need

```
varPane.getChildren().clear();
```

You can check if the pane's `parentProperty()` changes to null:

```
myPane.parentProperty().addListener((obs, oldParent, newParent) -> {
    if (newParent == null) {
         System.out.println("Pane closed: " + newV);
    }
});
```

Checking if the window containing the pane is hidden (closed) is considerably harder. You can create the following chain of listeners (basically listening to the pane's `sceneProperty()` in order to listen to the scene's `windowProperty()` in order to listener to the window's `showingProperty()`):

```
ChangeListener<Boolean> showingListener = (obs, wasShowing, isNowShowing) -> {
    if (! isNowShowing) {
        System.out.println("Window containing "+newV+" hidden");
    }
};
ChangeListener<Window> windowListener = (obs, oldWin, newWin) -> {
    if (oldWin != null) {
        oldWin.showingProperty().removeListener(showingListener);
    }
    if (newWin != null) {
        newWin.showingProperty().addListener(showingListener);
    }
};
ChangeListener<Scene> sceneListener = (obs, oldScene, newScene) -> {
    if (oldScene != null) {
        oldScene.windowProperty().removeListener(windowListener);
        if (oldScene.getWindow() != null) {
            oldScene.getWindow().showingProperty().removeListener(showingListener);
        }
    }
    if (newScene != null) {
        newScene.windowProperty().addListener(windowListener);
        if (newScene.getWindow() != null) {
            newScene.getWindow().showingProperty().addListener(showingListener);
        }
    }
};
myPane.sceneProperty().addListener(sceneListener);
```

You may prefer to use a bindings framework, such as the one that is part of [ReactFX](https://github.com/TomasMikula/ReactFX). Using ReactFX, you can cover both cases with

```
EventStreams.changesOf(Val
    .flatMap(myPane.sceneProperty(), Scene::windowProperty)
    .flatMap(Window::showingProperty)
    .orElseConst(false))
    .filter(c -> ! c.getNewValue())
    .observe(v -> System.out.println("Pane closed: "+newV));
```